# How do I prove I own/am the developer of an iOS app?

Tags: ios, development, developer-program

I am currently in the process of trying to secure a visa for overseas work. I recently developed an iOS app and need to provide proof or ownership or that I developed it. Is there a way to go about this? Can Apple provide a certificate or something? Any advice on this would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Is it a paid for app or have IAP - if so then you can shown income from Apple

Answer (score 1):

Is you app available in App Store? Is your name officially mentioned there as the author. If yes, then I would consider this as a proof.

Are you talking about being iOS developer in general or developer of particular iOS app? If first case is true then maybe your certificates of employment could solve the problem?

Comment: Hey, yes I am the independent developer of this app. I need to provide proof so I can apply for a work visa. As I did it in my own time I don't have a certificate of employment.

My name is listed as the author, but I'm wondering if this will be sufficient proof or not as two people could have the same name.

Comment: Answer my first question. Is your app in AppStore?

Comment: Yes, it is in the app store.

Comment: So I assume the answer is clear. If your name is mentioned as a developer and Apple approved the software then all should be clear. Or ask them to certify that or (I'm not joking) do a print screen of AppStore and go to notary and then sworn translator.

Answer (score 1):

You have the private key (developer signing certificate) that signed the application in the App Store. Sign (encrypt) a message containing your name with that private key, then tell the person wanting to verify your identity to decrypt that message with your public key (that is contained within the application). Your private key, and only your private key, can encrypt a message that can be successfully decrypted with your public key.

It's technical, I know, but this is the only guaranteed way to verify the identity of an application's developer.